# chrome css3 multi-column cursor bug

Tags: css-multicolumn-layout

In chrome recent versions, in the case of text inside a contenteditable div, using css3 multi-columnn mode, I am finding the following behaviour:

If a `<p>` element starts in one column and continues to the following column, the cursor will only be visible in the part of the `<p>` displayed in the second column. The cursor in the part of the `<p>` in the first column is invisible.

Any `<p>` element wholly contained in the first column is OK.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/oqr346hk/

Answer (score 2):

This bug is still ongoing in chrome as of version 78.   I think the  bug surfaced somewhere between 63.0.3239.132 and 64.0.3282.119

For anyone developing an nw.js or electron app using multicolumn css the only answer seems to be to revert to an earlier version of that framework.

The last bug-free nw.js version is 0.27.5 which uses chrome 63.0.3239.132.

Electron v 2.0.18 is fine .. it uses chrome 61.0.3163.100
Probably some later versions of electron would be ok also provided they embed up to chrome 63.

That chrome team hasn't fixed such an important bug is truly lamentable.

Comment: Yes, that is a real shame. Still looking for a vanilla JS solution to deal with this for a Laravel Vue app.